# Unpublished database updates in mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongodb collection  db.posts .

Posts has fields title, body, tags, author, images (array of objects), links (array of objects).

There are many admins who can edit these posts. When the post is created it is automatically available on the public website.  While the post is published I would like the admins to be able to edit the post and save the updates to the Mongo record. However those edits should not be seen publicly until approved.

What is the most efficient way to do this:-

1. Create a second collection titled db.publishedPosts and on approval copy the record from one collection to the other using a complete overwrite.
2. Save the updated fields in a nested object inside db.posts record.  db.posts.editedFields
3. Is there another common method or pattern for handling this kind of issue.

I am using meteorjs as my full stack application.

Comment: What is your definition of "efficient" here? Small database size? Client or server CPU usage? How much code you need to write? Other?

Comment: I'd probably go with option #1

Comment: @JesperWe minimal code

Answer (score 0):

If you want minimal code, more collections = more code so #1 seems wrong to me. You want to be able to reuse the form template you have already coded, and keep reactivity.

I would put all the fields inside subdocuments, for example a `.published.foobar` and an `.editor.foobar` etc.
You can then surround the public display template with `{{#with published}}` and keep all field variables inside it. Same with the editor template: `{{#with editor}}`. Your save function needs to be modified to save to the subdocument. Add a Publish button that copies `.editor` to `.published`.

As a bonus you can now have `.published` be an array that you `.push()` each edit to, and make a `published()` template helper that gets the lates published version. Then add dates and you have version control. ...but I am leaving the minimum code now, sorry :D